# Empty returned array

Tags: python

I am solving Project Euler problem 11. I wrote a code to convert a 400 integer long array into a 20 x 20 2D array. The print statement shows the correct array, but return statement, returns a list, with 20 empty list elements. I wrote the code on python 2.7 on windows XP but the code isn't working on Google Collab as well. Help...

```
def convert_to_arr(str):

    arr=[int(i) for i in str.split()]

    return arr

def convert_array(arrays):
    arr = []
    holder=[]

    for i in range(20):
        for j in range(i*20,(i+1)*20):
            holder.append(arrays[j])

        arr.append(holder)
        print(arr)
        holder*=0
   


    return arr
```

Answer (score 0):

Python lists are mutable

```
def convert_to_arr(str):

    arr=[int(i) for i in str.split()]

    return arr

def convert_array(arrays):
    arr = []
    holder=[]

    for i in range(20):
        for j in range(i*20,(i+1)*20):
            holder.append(arrays[j])

        arr.append(holder)
        print(arr)
        holder = []
        # holder*=0 #lists are mutable # you are emptying the list here
    return arr
```

Comment: But I am returning the array arr. I am using holder to store 20 elements and then I am appending them to arr. I also thought about this, but I am clearing the holder array after appending it to arr.

Comment: arrays/lists are mutable, you are appending the pointer and then changing there value